# java smack facebook get unseen messages

Tags: java, facebook, xmpp, smack

I would like to receive messages from the offline(unseen) facebook. but I am getting this error.
facebook does not support this feature?

feature-not-implemented(501)at org.jivesoftware.smackx.OfflineMessageManager.getMessages(OfflineMessageManager.java:210)
    at ktg_msn.test.main(test.java:58)

my code

```
 try {
     ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222, "chat.facebook.com");
     config.setSendPresence(false);
     XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
     connection.connect();
     connection.login("userrr", "passs");


     OfflineMessageManager offlineManager = new OfflineMessageManager(connection);

     System.out.println(offlineManager.getMessageCount());

     Iterator<Message> it = offlineManager.getMessages();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
         Message m = it.next();
         String fromName = m.getFrom();
         Date currentDate = new Date();
         String text = m.getBody() + " (offline)";
         System.out.println(text);
     }    
 } catch (XMPPException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: u got any solution???